I can't understand how to send login credentials with JMeter
I need to perform a login test and keep the session active for subsequent requests in JMeter, but by analyzing the code from the browser, I can't understand how to send the login data and what I need to intercept to keep the session active.

When I access the site via the web to intercept the HTTP requests, a popup appears, but from the browser's inspect element, I cannot find the popup data to use in JMeter. enter image description here

After a successful authentication, I can't find the credentials in any request.enter image description here

I noticed that a JSESSIONID is provided, which probably keeps the session open. Can you help me understand how to perform this login?enter image description here



JSESSIONID can be handled using HTTP Cookie Manager, it's sufficient to add it and it will take care of the cookie automatically.
The "pop-up" means that an external authentication subsystem being used, it needs to be handled with HTTP Authorization Manager. For Basic access authentication it is enough to provide credentials, for other types configuration will be more complex, see Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter article for more details
